# proteolysis - how to determine the partial or completeness of the cleavage reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond, biochemistry, hydrolysis, proteins

Though the question is about biomolecules, we agree the underlying functions, formation, degradation etc come down to chemistry, (then physics and maths). I am posting it here to receive an understanding from chemistry perspective. I am referring [this info here to grasp the concept.](https://www.liverpool.ac.uk/~agmclen/Medpracs/practical_3/theory_3.html)

e.g. Trypsin is a protease that regulates specific hydrolysis/proteolysis by cleaving at the c terminus side of Arg and Lys.

Similarly, given two catalysts: (proteases) papain and bromelain. Both are said to regulate selective peptide cleavage reactions (specificity of proteolysis) - breaking peptide (amide) bond from C-terminal analysis (enzymatic hydrolysis). This is clear to me.

[image]

These enzymes only break c-terminus peptide bonds of specific amino acids. e.g. Papain for Arg and Leu. Bromelain for Ala, Leu, Ser, Gly, Tyr.

How to determine if papain or bromelain hydrolyse a given polypeptide chain **completely or partially**? And what's the resulting residue and chain? I am not expecting an one-liner, I want to understand the reaction mechanism and concept clearly for further application.

e.g. what's the resulting fragments of this after Papain act on it?

Arg-Leu-Ser-Ala-Tyr

Comment: @Martin-マーチン the poor question is lying here for weeks. Some of your expert advice and insight would be very helpful.

Comment: Are you asking experimentally how to work out if the peptide has been cleaved? Or asking if the enzymes given will cleave the example pentapeptide sequence ?

Comment: @Baran I am asking for the latter. I have started to read on Edman degradation. But not sure if that's the theory I need to read about. Is there resource/articles at y1 Uni level, explaining the concepts how certain enzymes do selective cleavage, the resulting amino acids sequences, and whether it's partial or complete. I do feel that my question is not clear enough as I am a bit lost in terms of the context of this whole scenario.

Comment: A biochemistry textbook would probably be a good place to start. Lehninger and Berg are both great books and cover proteins

Comment: @NotBaran do you know which part of Berg I should look at? Do you know what concept is this question trying to test?

Comment: A possibly helpful paper (I'd try to read it and answer your question, but I can't access the paper from where I am....): http://rstb.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/257/813/237

Comment: @ChildishJack I updated my question, the main issue remains the same. I am not able to find a proper reference within Yr 1,2 Uni levels to sort an answer in determining partial or completeness of the cleaving process/reaction.